# Django: Defining form media in class-based views

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

While using a class-based view like:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
```

How can I define custom CSS and JavaScript to be loaded by `{{ form.media }}` in the `myapp/mymodel_form.html` template?

I could set the `form_class` attribute and use the [`Media`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/#media-on-forms) subclass, but I'm wondering if there's direct way without creating more classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is the media property

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/media/#dynamic-property

If you are looking for simplicity, an alternative would be to use template inheritance by creating a media block in your base template and specifying your media in child templates. However, it may duplicate media definitions.